# Id cannot find the .so library

Tags: c++, linker, g++, .a

I am attempting link an app with my compiler, however, ld is warning it cannot find specified libraries. This is the last one that I cannot handle.

I am calling the linker with:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG XXX -o ijkmcube -lNrrdIO,-rpath,XXX:
```

Id warned that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lNrrdIO
```

Since this library seems like not that popular, I cannot find direct `apt install` method to handle it.

Furthermore, I could only find out  `.a` library instead of `.so` library for this particular case.

`locate libNrrdIO.a`

`/home/XXX/Desktop/NrrdIO-1.11.0-src/libNrrdIO.a`
`/home/XXX/Desktop/src/ijkmcube/lib/libNrrdIO.a`

How do I diagnose this problem further, and what could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is a static library, just list it along your sources: `c++ main.cpp /home/XXX/Desktop/src/ijkmcube/lib/libNrrdIO.a`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just add my `.a` library to the path after `-L`. Many thanks!